# Issue in URL Splitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have write following code to split the URL

```
var href = document.URL;
var GlobalBoomGuid = href.split("=");
var optionid = GlobalBoomGuid[1];
```

If i have URL like this : [www.mydomain.com?optionid=655](http://www.google.com) It's giving me **"655"** .

But in current scenario my URL is [www.mydomain.com?optionid=655#&ui-state=dialog](http://www.google.com) and it's returning me **655#&ui-state**

Now i want only id . How should i do that ?

**Please if you dont like the question don't mark as a Negative**

Thanx in Advance :)

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets your result

```
var href =  document.URL;
var foo = href.split("=")[1];
var GlobalBoomGuid = foo.split("#")[0];
var optionid = GlobalBoomGuid;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7x6h8y5g/)